# Would like to get some information

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, xcode4.5

I'm an iOS Developer & New to COCOA Mac Development.

I'd like to know some essential websites and blogs (for a beginner) that can help me.

Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: This question is not constructive.

Comment: Thanks for feedback Popeye :) I'll take care of it

Comment: thanks Liam George Betsworth

Comment: I haven't downvoted cause I find these questions are always useful even though they don't provide factual answers and they only provide opinions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a different approach to iOS from Code School. http://tryobjectivec.codeschool.com

Comment: It's very useful and good site to learn online :) thanks Jahm

Comment: No problem. Glad the site can help you. Happy learning, and happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

Get the following books (in this order)

**Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X** by Hillegass Preble - [Amazon link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321774086)

**Advanced Mac OS X Programming** by Mark Dalrymple - [Amazon link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321706250)

**Xcode 4** by Richard Wentk - [Amazon link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/111800759X)

And for **online study** watch this series on youtube: [Cocoa Tutorials](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLE83F832121568D36)

Comment: Read the first book and watch the youtube videos. Keep the other two books for reference when you need it.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend ray wenderlich's site, it has a variety of tutorials ranging from starters to advanced

http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials